# Is the loop time in asyncio the same as time.monotonic?

Tags: python, python-asyncio

Are these the same clock? `time.monotonic()` and `asyncio.get_event_loop().time()`. It seems to be the case on my system, but I cannot find any related documentation except this sentence:

> Event loop uses monotonic clocks to track time.

However that does not imply that those two clocks have the same absolute value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that's how it is implemented:

```
class BaseEventLoop(events.AbstractEventLoop):
    (...)

    def time(self):
        """Return the time according to the event loop's clock.
        This is a float expressed in seconds since an epoch, but the
        epoch, precision, accuracy and drift are unspecified and may
        differ per event loop.
        """
        return time.monotonic()
```

See more here: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/fb2c3465f09e1f720cdae7eca87d62125a327fd9/Lib/asyncio/base_events.py#L635

Note that this holds for the default event loop. And `asyncio.get_event_loop()` can be overwritten to return some other implementation. And thus this is an implementation detail and you should not depend on that.

Comment: This answer correctly references the implementation, but the actual contract stated by the cited documentation is that **no**, you cannot rely on `loop.time()` returning values compatible with `time.monotonic()` - it might be implemented using a different clock in the future.

Answer (score 3):

> However that does not imply that those two clocks have the same absolute value.

True, and in fact it states the exact opposite, that the event loop may use any monotonic clock whatsoever. The **current implementation** just calls `time.monotonic()` - which is not documented - but a future one may switch to, say, a more efficient clock that returns values different from those returned by `time.monotonic()`.

Having said that, note that it is not very *likely* for such a switch to happen, but as far as the [`loop.time()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.time) contract is concerned, it is allowed.